# Помогите пожалуйста понять ООП в python на данном участке кода:

Tags: python, ооп, cocos2d

```py
import cocos

class HelloCocos(cocos.layer.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        label = cocos.text.Label("Hello Cocos", font_name = "Times New Roman", font_size = 32, anchor_x = "center", anchor_y = "center")
        label.position = 640, 360
        self.add(label)


cocos.director.director.init(width=1280, height=720, caption="CatGame")

hello_layer = HelloCocos()

test_scene = cocos.scene.Scene(hello_layer)

cocos.director.director.run(test_scene)
```

Я новичок, и до сих пор не понимаю Классы в python.
У меня есть несколько вопросов:

1. Зачем при создании класса подается `cocos.layer.Layer`
2. Что делает функция `__init__` и что значит `self`
3. Что значит `super().__init__()`
4. Что значит `self.add(label)`
5. Зачем некоторые программисты пишут if `__name__ == "__main__":`?

Comment: Лучше разбить этот вопрос на несколько вопросов, для быстроты поиска ответа. И посмотрите может они уже задавались тут.

Comment: На **все** вопросы есть ответы в учебнике. Ты не пробовал открыть его?

Comment: @Эникейщик я не смог связать данный участок кода с материалом в учебнике.
Не очень понял.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По порядку:

- Тут из библиотеки вызывается класс, уже содержащий какие-то атрибуты и функции. В данном случае, класс **HelloCocos** наследует **Layer**.
- `__init__` - функция инициализация экземпляра класса. (Не путать с `__new__`, она создает объект.) Ключевое слово **self** - указатель на созданный экземпляр. Т.е. для того, чтобы вызвать атрибут\функцию экземпляра, надо обратиться к нему через его указатель (self).
- `super().__init__()` - точно такая же инициализация экземпляра класса, но для класса **Layer**, от которого унаследован класс **HelloCocos**.
- `self.add(label)` - вызывает у текущего экземпляра класса функцию `add(label)`, которая, вероятнее всего, описана внутри класса **Layer**.
- `__name__ == "__main__":` - хорошая практика и точка входа в программу. В Python она не обязательна. Очень полезна при написании модулей. Код, который будет написан внутри данной конструкции, будет исполняться только в случае, если файл, где описан код, будет запущен напрямую, а не вызван в другом файле.